# JQuery in files loaded using JQuery tabs

Tags: php, jquery, css

This is my first attempt to use JQuery tabs. I have a simple file that loads 3 other php files when the tabs are clicked.

```
<div id="info">
    <ul id="info-nav">
        <li><a href="tab1.php">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab2.php">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab3.php">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#info').tabs();
    });

</script>
```

The php files use JQuery also and are loaded correctly. When I test the files stand-alone, the JQuery parts work fine. But once they are loaded into the tabs, the JQuery doesn't work. Even a simple alert in the $(document).ready(function()...) in the loaded file doesn't show.Is there some conflict between the JQuery in the 2 files? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, there could be. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: No, the HTML portions render fine with all the checkboxes, buttons, etc. No errors. But the JQuery parts don't work.

Comment: Did you open the console and look? or did you just assume that since the html is rendering properly there are no errors (which is not a safe assumption...)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the console check. Didn't know about Firebug & so installed and activated it on the page to debug. The problem turned out to be not related to JQuery at all. The standalone php files were receiving some vars via POST from the calling page. Since I introduced a new page with the tabs, the loaded files no longer got those vars and caused the JS functions to fail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conflict per se, but one of two things is happening:

- The browser is declining to execute the contents of <script> tags in dynamically loaded content;
- The browser is executing the <script> tags, but the `ready` event is not being fired on the document object when the content is dynamically loaded.

The second is almost certainly true; the first may also be.

To find out which case is occurring, instead of putting an `alert()` inside the `$(document).ready()` callback, put it simply within the <script> tag of a given HTML file, and then reload and select the tab that loads that HTML file dynamically. In the first case described above (<script> tags not being executed at all), the alert will not be displayed; in the second case (the ready event not firing), it will.

If the code is being executed at all, then all you need do is take your code out of the callback and wrap it in bare <script> tags; it will be executed as soon as the browser sees it. Otherwise -- and I'd suggest this is advisable in any case, for maintainability reasons -- you'll need to rework your application so that it does not rely on executing Javascript contained within random <script> tags scattered throughout your various HTML files, but instead uses some unified handler to deal with whatever needs doing when tab content is loaded.

Comment: code inside a document ready will be executed immediately if the dom is already ready, so that can't be it. The scripts simply aren't being executed. It has nothing to do with the browser, most likely jQuery UI is stripping the scripts out of it, or an error is occurring thus stopping the script.